# How to compute the function: 100*((GDP-GDPpotential)/GDPpotential) and get the value in a new dataset?

Tags: r, function

Can some one please explain how to do this simple function so that I get a column of numbers with the results from the function?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYtqe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting to create a new column with the results? If so, then you can use `mutate` with the formula.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(result = 100*((GDP-GDPpotential)/GDPpotential))
```

**Output**

```
  GDP GDPpotential    result
1 2.5            3 -16.66667
2 3.0            2  50.00000
3 3.5            6 -41.66667
4 4.0            3  33.33333
5 4.5            1 350.00000
```

Or in base R:

```
df$result <- 100*((df$GDP-df$GDPpotential)/df$GDPpotential)
```